# Remove a directory in jenkins before the git checkout happens

Tags: jenkins

I am using the cleanup feature in Jenkins, which delete the previous build directory and create a new one every time. This is great, except that I need to maintain certain files in the build directory, so I am trying to delete just the source folder that contain the code.

The problem is that when the build start, the first thing that happen is the git checkout of the code, which means that if I put a delete command in the jenkins script area, it will delete the directory that was checked out, and that obviously won't work.

Is there a way to tell Jenkins to perform commands before the git checkout happen? Or to cleanup selectively the build folder, so Jenkins know what to keep and what to delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [pre-scm-buildstep](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/pre-scm-buildstep) plugin. It will let you do all sorts of things prior to touching your SCM.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can configure your Jenkins pipeline and add:
**Wipe out repository & force clone** option in **Additional Behaviours** of `SCM configuration` or `Branch Sources`:

[image]

This way, you will make sure the working directory will be cleaned [including all previous files and the previous `.git` folder if exist as well] before git checkout.

Also, you will find the following log line in your job logs:

```
Wiping out workspace first.
```