# How to clear workspace in Jenkins pipeline before job starts

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to clear workspace before build starts. I tried using `cleanDir()` in stages, but in the declarative pipeline, check out happens first and when stage with `cleadDir` runs, checked out code also gets cleared which is not desired. How can we clear the workspace before check out in the declarative pipeline?

Comment: related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78078076/1824361

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the means of your VCS, with Git run

```
git clean -fdx
```

Comment: This is so much simpler than all other solutions I have seen, and it displays what files it has cleared up in output too.

Comment: Nowadays you can do [$class: 'CleanCheckout']. This executes git clean

Comment: I guess that's the pipeline way of what I've posted on Sep 13, 2017 at 6:03, isn't it?

Answer (score 19):

Actually, I have to revise my answer based on recent changes to the pipeline plugins, e.g. GitHub Branch Source Plugin 2.2.0 with [JENKINS-43507](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43507).

Besides the different branch discovery behaviours, which can be configured, one can now define additional steps to take, including *Clean before checkout* (and *Clean after checkout*):

[image]

The resulting output in the pipeline execution will then be

> ```
> Cleaning workspace
>   > git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10
> Resetting working tree
>  > git reset --hard # timeout=10
>  > git clean -fdx # timeout=10
> ```

so, pretty close to the calling `git clean` yourself.

Comment: I noticed this option after the update. if we have a multi pipeline job and we might not have to delete for all branches. In that case, git clean makes it easier.

Comment: I would love if there was a way to delete the .git folder here. It is kinda corrupted and it hanhs on git reset hard here

Comment: @MartinKosicky Just add a step `sh('rm -rf .git/')`?

Comment: I mean the pipeline pulling stage. Not execution of the pipeline

Answer (score 15):

```
stage('Git') {
            steps {
                step([$class: 'WsCleanup'])
                checkout scm
            }
        }
```

the WsCleanup does the trick

Comment: This removes the workspace directory from within this directory and can result in `error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory`. Better use `sh 'rm -rf *'` as the first step of the first stage after you allocated your workspace.

Comment: It's VERY risky calling `sh 'rm -rf *'`, because you may not be in the directory you think you're in - if you're at `/`, you've very likely just blew away your OS.

Answer (score 3):

Add **Wipe out repository & force clone** in **Additional Behaviours** of SCM configuration as on picture below:

[image]

Comment: This is the only answer that removes also the .git folder which may be corrupt, together with any submodules with bad URLs registered, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
            env.WORKSPACE = pwd()
            sh "rm ${env.WORKSPACE}/* -fr"
```

Comment: This deletes the checked out code too when called from a step.

Comment: This deletes the whole workspace like you asked. I got a job where i do this before checking out the code, so it kinda made sense to me.

Comment: When you say before checking out the code, do you check out the code in next step in the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach would be to use the [stash step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-stash-code-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build) to stash your code first:

```
stash includes: 'src/**', name: 'source-code'
```

After that you can delete everything in your current Workspace. In a later stage you can simply [unstash](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-unstash-code-restore-files-previously-stashed) the source code again:

```
unstash 'source-code'
```

Another advantage of stash/unstash is that you can use it to share files between multiple jenkins nodes.

Comment: Looks like @StephenKing answer is the simplest way. In one shot it works, have put in real project and check the impact.

Comment: Agreed. `git clean` is a very nice solution for this. Thought the stash/unstash approach is worth sharing anyways as it comes in very handy when running in multi slave node environments.

Comment: @StephenKing Hmm i rarely have gigs of code in my vcs. In that case checkouts in jenkins are painful anyways.. Besides, what more efficient option there is to share code between nodes?