# How do I checkout one file in Jenkins GitSCM

Tags: jenkins

I have this in my Jenkins pipeline build file:

```
def gitResponse = dir(gitPath) { checkout([
  $class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']],
  userRemoteConfigs: [[url: gitUrl,credentialsId:'my-key']]
]) }
```

And it works just fine.  The problem comes where a developer, (not me) runs a script during a python build of some kind.  It changes a file, (in this case called setup.py)  and when it comes to bundling it up and publishing to our npm repo,  npm throws this error:

```
npm ERR! Git working directory not clean.
npm ERR! D backend/sdk/setup.py
```

So what I need to do one of 2 things,  either ignore this file somehow  (even though that file is in my .gitignore, and .npmignore)  or delete it and checkout that file and that file only.

How can I do this with the GitSCM plugin?

Comment: I don't think Git works that way. You can check out the latest version into a folder, but you'd have to copy over the file in question after that point. AFAIK, that is.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have checked out your branch, you could add a step which would:

- either execute `git clean -fdx`
- or use a [WsCleanup class step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46190227/6309) in order to clean the Workspace.

Those are not directly using GitSCM, but GitSCM extension `CleanBeforeCheckout` seems to [have a pending issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32540).
In a non-multibranch setting, you can still try:

```
  checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']],
        userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'your_url_here']],
        extensions: [[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout']]])
```